# fedora with cinnamon desktop: ibus pinyin only works if system locale is switched to chinese

Tags: cinnamon, input-method, ibus

I am having a weird issue with `ibus-pinyin`. I am running Fedora 28 with the Cinnamon desktop (dnf groupinstall "Cinnamon Desktop"), and I occasionally type Chinese. I installed `ibus` and `ibus-pinyin`, a couple of extra i18n fonts, and I put

```
ibus-daemon -drx
```

in my user's `.xprofile` file. This works all nice & dandy if I switch my user's desktop to "Chinese" in `Preferences -> Language`. I can then switch between Chinese pinyin and English IME input just fine.

However, if I set my user's locale to `EN/US`, the `ibus` daemon doesn't start (or at least there's no applet on the panel), and if I start it manually afterwards, I can switch between `ZH/CN` and `EN/US` in the applet, but my input stays on the English IME.

I am not even sure where to start looking ... does anyone have any ideas?